# MySQL: Перекодировка результата запроса к БД

Tags: кодировка, cp1251, utf-8, mysql

У меня есть БД в cp1251_general_ci. Так исторически сложилось. И всё было хорошо до смены хостинга. Теперь их сервер отдаёт мне контент в utf-8 (что и выводит в HTML). Хотелось бы решить проблему концептуально правильно. 
Я предполагаю, что лучшее - если сервер будет отдавать записи в реальной кодировке. И подозреваю, что это связано с MySQL connection collation.
Если это так, то далее мне видятся 2 варианта:
1. Создать копию БД с указанием MySQL connection collation cp1251_general_ci и далее использовать её в качестве основной (исходную удалить).
2. Указывать **COLLATION** в запросе.
Очень надеюсь услышать мнения/опровержения/предложения по существу от коллег, компетентных в данном вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку реальных идей нет, выкладываю решение, найденное по результатам собственного исследования.
Смысл в принудительной установке кодировки при отправке_запроса/получении_ответа от сервера. Сразу после установления связи с БД (mysql_connect ($server,$user,$pass);) прописываем:

```
mysql_query ("set character_set_client='cp1251'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='cp1251'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='cp1251_general_ci'");
```